# Why does this add data to the database multiple times?

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I have created a set of php files that have a simple job:

Allows a user to log in.
Allows that user to upload a file.
Then Allows the user to see all files they have uploaded.

Strangely though, when I upload a file through 1 user name, the file list result shows the same result 4 times then I uploaded a second file, it appeared 5 times. With another user it displays it 5 times.

I checked the place the files get stored after upload, and there is only 1 copy of each file there. Below is my code, any help?

index.php - This has login form, file upload form and finally the download list

```
        <?
    break;
    }
?>
<?php if ($_SESSION['username']): ?>
    <h1>Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION["username"] ?></h1></br>
    <?php
//include ("config.php");
    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpwd);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db($dbname);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");

        }

?>  
    Select File To Upload
<div style="width:100%; margin:5px;">
<form action="uploadclientfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload" style="margin:5px;">
<label> File</label>
<input name="uploaded_file" type="file" class="input-xlarge" required/>
<input type="hidden" name="" value="<?php $_SESSION['username'] ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" /><br /><br />
<input name="Upload" type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn" />
</form>
</div></br></br>

File list:</br>
<?php
$userfiles = mysql_query("SELECT filename, filelocation FROM cfiles WHERE userid='{$_SESSION['username']}'" );
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($userfiles)) {
    $filename = $row['filename'];
    $filelocation = $row['filelocation'];   
echo "<a href=".$filelocation .">" .$filename . "</a><br />"; 
} ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<a href="index.php?action=login">Log-in</a> | <a href="index.php?action=logout">Log-out</a><br />
</body>
</html>
```

and also upload.php

```
 <?php 
 session_start(); 
 echo( "<pre>" );
 print_r( $_POST );
 print_r( $_FILES );
 echo( "</pre>" );



 $target = "userfiles/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']); 

  $new_file_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $target);

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $userid = $_SESSION['username'];  
 $file = basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'] );


// Cycle through each member and check that it needs to be added to the db
$useruploadids = mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM members" );
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($useruploadids))
{
        //Writes the information to the database 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cfiles` VALUES ('{$userid}', '{$file}', '{$new_file_name}')") or die( mysql_error() ) ; 
}

 //Writes the file to the server 
 if( @move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $new_file_name ) ) 
 { 
    //Tells you if its all ok 
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'] ). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory."; 
 } 
 else
 { 
    //Gives and error if its not 
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 ?>
```

So there are the 2 main files used in this process. Any help as to why my file is appearing in the download list and mysql database multiple times? It is only appearing once in the folder it is stored.

Comment: Help us help you by *a) eliminating any irrelevant code to the problem scope* and *b) formatting your code properly*

Answer (score 3):

This part of your code:

```
// Cycle through each member and check that it needs to be added to the db
$useruploadids = mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM members" );
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($useruploadids))
{
    //Writes the information to the database 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cfiles` VALUES ('{$userid}', '{$file}', '{$new_file_name}')") or die( mysql_error() ) ; 
}
```

Loops through how ever many users you have and adds a new file entry for each.  So if you have 5 users you add 5 entries into `cfiles` for the `$userid` of the person that's logged in.  This will increase with more users.

Is this what you meant to do?  You probably just want to add one entry for that user, and not other users, correct?

If you remove the loop and replace that code with this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cfiles` VALUES ('{$userid}', '{$file}', '{$new_file_name}')") or die( mysql_error() ) ;
```

You'll only get one entry

Comment: Aha. I used this snippet of code from another upload form I used that has tick boxes so multiple users can have the same file. That makes sense. So if I remove this It will solve the problem?

Comment: Just remove the `SELECT` and the `while` loop

Comment: Yes, just use the line that's inside the loop, and delete the loop.

Comment: yep just removed the bits that cycle, along with the brackets, looks like it works now. getting a header error on the upload file, but I will sort that another time  :P

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/outbreak/public_html/nigel/uploadclientfile.php:1) in /home/outbreak/public_html/nigel/uploadclientfile.php on line 2

Answer (score 1):

This code confuses me:

```
// Cycle through each member and check that it needs to be added to the db
$useruploadids = mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM members" );
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($useruploadids))
{
        //Writes the information to the database 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cfiles` VALUES ('{$userid}', '{$file}', '{$new_file_name}')") or die( mysql_error() ) ; 
}
```

What are you trying to do here? It appears that you're inserting the uploaded file into the database multiple times, one time for each user who exists. Why are you doing that? Is that why the file is appearing multiple times? (Seems likely to me)

Comment: hey is that really an answer?

Comment: The question is unclear @FélixGagnon-Grenier. I believe this is the source of his problem; I was seconds behind the other answer which is essentially the same thing.

Comment: Yes, it is; see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416346/why-does-this-add-data-to-the-database-multiple-times/21416503#comment32308335_21416491): *yep just removed the bits that cycle, along with the brackets, looks like it works now*

Comment: It did seemed pretty on-topic, I was wondering if it was or not a SO guideline to formulate answers with more affirmative sentences. But you had the answer with your questions, as you say.